# Solucionar problema de printf con hilos sincronizados

Tags: c, hilos

Estoy haciendo un programa que lee una serie de datos de un fichero, estos datos son leidos mediante un único hilo lector y procesados mediante 3 hilos consumidores, el programa se ejecuta correctamente sin embargo si quito o comento el printf `printf("%d\n", contador)` el programa pasa a entrar en un bucle infinito. Esto solo ocurre cuando los hilos consumidores son varios y por tanto necesitan recursos compartidos, es por ello que creo que el problema puede ocurrir por culpa de la alteración de una de estas variables compartidas por culpa de el printf, pero no entiendo de que forma esta afectando, ni siquiera porque tendría que afectar una instrucción de tipo printf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define LINEA 30

char *fich_cod = "fichero.txt";
int cont_l = -1;
int siguiente, contador = 0;
int *array;

sem_t hay_espacio, hay_datos, mutex_array, mutex_index;

void *leer() {
        FILE *fich;
        fich = fopen(fich_cod, "r");
        if (fich == NULL) {
                exit(-1);
        }
        char* linea;
        linea = malloc(LINEA*sizeof(char));
        int cont, sig = 0;
        while (fgets(linea, LINEA, fich) != NULL) {
                cont++;
                sem_wait(&hay_espacio);
                sem_wait(&mutex_array);
                while (array[sig] == 0) {
                        sig = (sig + 1)%3;
                }
                // TODO Meter dato en buffer
                array[sig] = 0;
                sem_post(&mutex_array);
                sem_post(&hay_datos);
                sig = (sig + 1)%3;
        }
        cont_l = cont;
        sem_post(&hay_datos);

        fclose(fich);

        printf("El hilo lector ha terminado\n");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *cons() {
        int sig = 0;
        while(1) {
                sem_wait(&hay_datos);
                printf("%d\n", contador);
                if (contador == cont_l) {
                        sem_post(&hay_datos);
                        break;
                }
                sem_wait(&mutex_array);
                sem_wait(&mutex_index);
            while (array[siguiente] == 1) {
                        siguiente = (siguiente + 1)%3;
                }
                sig = siguiente;
                siguiente = (siguiente + 1)%3;
                sem_post(&mutex_index);
                // TODO recoger dato buffer
                array[sig] = 1;
                sem_post(&mutex_array);
                contador++;
                sem_post(&hay_espacio);
                // TODO Procesar datos
        }
        printf("Un hilo consumidor ha terminado\n");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
        sem_init(&hay_espacio, 0, 3);
        sem_init(&hay_datos, 0, 0);
        sem_init(&mutex_array, 0, 1);
        sem_init(&mutex_index, 0, 1);

        array = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                array[i] = 1;
        }

        pthread_t hlector;
        pthread_create(&hlector, NULL, leer, NULL);
        pthread_t hcons[3];
        for (int i; i < 3; i++) {
                pthread_create(&hcons[i], NULL, cons, NULL);
        }
        pthread_join(hlector, NULL);
        for (int i; i < 3; i++) {
                pthread_join(hcons[i], NULL);
        }

        sem_destroy(&hay_espacio);
        sem_destroy(&hay_datos);
        sem_destroy(&mutex_array);
        sem_destroy(&mutex_index);
        free(array);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mutex_array es pata sincronizar el contador y mutex_index el buffer siguiente ¿cierto? Si es así entonces el ``contador++`` debería estar antes que liberes el semaforo y ``sem_wait(mutex_array)`` debe estar antes del ``if(contador==c9nt-l)`` ya que debes asegurarte que nadie cambie contador mientras haces el if. Los semáforos deben proteger a las variables gompartidas entre elnwait y el post

Comment: Y antes del `break` liberas el semaforo. El lector también utiliza el.mutex array no debería ser el index. Creo que tienes un problema de orden

Comment: Mutex_array sirve para sincronizar el acceso a array no al contador, pero gracias por el comentario, pues tras crear otro semáforo para el acceso al contador  he podido solucionar el problema, pense en un principio que no haría falta un semáforo para contador ya que solo se lee su valor, pero claro estaba equivocado.  Por tanto el problema no era de printf, sino que este simplemente ralentizaba la ejecución del hilo y hacía que siempre el valor de contador fuera correcto